# How to download data in git, but not merge it

Tags: git

Which command will I use if I want to download new data from a remote git repository, but I do not want this data to be automatically merged into my working files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git fetch can fetch from either a single named repository or URL, or from several repositories at once if  is given and there is a remotes. entry in the configuration file.

```
git fetch [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]
```

You can refer the below link for more information.
[git fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

Answer (score 1):

That's what `git fetch` does. `git pull` is, in some sense, a convenience wrapper around `git fetch` and `git merge`.

`git fetch` provides the ability to download commits from individual branches. You can also use `git remote update`, which downloads *all* new commits, regardless of which branch provides access to them.